# Submitting multiple forms with single button in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on my school project, a website where admin (a teacher) can create tests and provide it to the students. It's been only 4 months since I started with PHP and I suddenly got stuck with the forms.

When admin presses the button to create the test, the page opens **questionsCount.php** , this contains a simple form, where admin gives a name to the test and types how many questions the test will have.

[questionsCount.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkCh3.png)

the script send the data to **newTest.php**

```
<?php
$nazovTestu = $_POST['nazovTestu'];
$pocetOtazok = $_POST['pocetOtazok'];

for($i = 1; $i <= $pocetOtazok; $i++){
    echo "<p class='pCenter'> Otazka: $i";
    stav();
}
?>
```

As you can see it has a cycle which calls a function stav() from script called **newQuestion.php**

```
<?php
 function stav(){
  echo " <br><br><br>
 <form>
  <table>  
   <tr>
    <td> <textarea class='otazkaField' name='otazkaName' id='' cols='30' 
      rows='5'></textarea> </td>
   </tr>

   <tr class='trBreak'>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Spravna odpoved: </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>    
    <td>A<input type='radio' name='moznostA'> <input type='text'> </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>B<input type='radio' name='moznostA'> <input type='text'> </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>C<input type='radio' name='moznostA'> <input type='text'> </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>D<input type='radio' name='moznostA'> <input type='text'> </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form> <br><br><br><hr>";}
?>
```

So basically when admin types the name of the test and the count of questions and presses submit button, the **newtest.php** script opens with the count of forms same as the count of questions.

[newTest.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mXOI.png)

Now I should implement a button that simply saves all questions and answers into database. But I'm not sure how I can do that with a single button. I haven't thought about other solution, like using JavaScript, because my JS skills are pretty poor and I'm really a PHP beginner.

Comment: Move `<form>` tags from the `stav()` function to the HTML. Before the closing `<form>`, add a submit `<button>`. Then you will get all your answers in the `$_POST` variable. Do not forget the `action` and `method` attribtutes of your `<form>`, and do not forget to have different `name` attributes for each of your radio `<input>` group.

Answer (score 0):

put all in the same form 
you remove form tag from newTest.php

and for newQuestion.php, change your code like this :

```
echo '<form>';
    for($i = 1; $i <= $pocetOtazok; $i++){
        echo "<p class='pCenter'> Otazka: $i";
        stav();

    }
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: That alone won’t do it, the radio buttons will all be considered to belong to one single group then … the `name` attribute has to be modified accordingly to preserve the same functionality as before.

Comment: change name of radio buttons, you can do it with the counter of your loop 'for' 
for exemple name='moznostA' will become name='moznostA_$i'. you can parse it after

Comment: I have done it, so it looks like this [link](https://codeshare.io/Gky0NV) right now, but when I try to display the input [link](https://codeshare.io/ayANpe), even if I only ask for 1 question inside the test, it gives me these: Notice: Undefined index: otazkaName_$i in C:\xampp\htdocs\tiu_projekt_3_19_19\php\testovanie\saveTest.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: moznostA_$i in C:\xampp\htdocs\tiu_projekt_3_19_19\php\testovanie\saveTest.php on line 12
..................

Comment: Problem resolved. I used arrays and its currently working.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach for this would be actually rendering beginning of the form before going through any questions

```
echo " <br><br><br>
    <form>
        <table>";

for($i = 1; $i <= $pocetOtazok; $i++){
    echo "<p class='pCenter'> Otazka: $i";
    stav();
}

echo
    " <input type='submit' value='save'>
    </table>
</form> <br><br><br><hr>";
```

Don't forget to specify form action etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define form action, method and submit button outside of your function.

```
    <?php
    echo " <br><br><br>
     <form action="answer.php" method="post" >
     function stav(){
         $z = 
      <table>  
       <tr>
        <td> <textarea class='questionField' name="questionName".$z id='' cols='30' 
          rows='5'></textarea> </td>
       </tr>

       <tr class='trBreak'>
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>Select the answer: </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>    
        <td>A<input type='radio' name='possibilityA' value ='1'> Vaša možnosť1 </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>B<input type='radio' name='possibilityA' value ='2'> Vaša možnosť2 </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>C<input type='radio' name='possibilityA' value ='3'> Vaša možnosť3 </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
        <td>D<input type='radio' name='possibilityA' value ='4'> Vaša možnosť4 </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
    <br><br><br><hr>";
$z++;
}
    <input type="submit">
    </form> 
    ?>
```